# How can I change one variabcd wad le in array?

Tags: json

I have this data of temperature:

xarray.Variable time: 8256 depth_t: 15

x = ([[28.22,   nan,   nan, ...,   nan,   nan,   nan], [28.35,   nan,   nan, ...,   nan,   nan,   nan], [28.07,   nan,   nan, ...,   nan,   nan,   nan], ..., [  nan, 27.23, 27.18, ...,   nan,   nan,   nan], [  nan, 27.23, 27.21, ...,   nan,   nan,   nan], [  nan, 27.19, 27.14, ...,   nan,   nan,   nan]], dtype=float32)

x.shape (8256,15)

This variable contains time and depth_t. I would like to replace only the time for the new time:

newtime: Index(['1999-03-06', '1999-03-07', '1999-03-08', '1999-03-09', '1999-03-10', '1999-03-11', '1999-03-12', '1999-03-13', '1999-03-14', '1999-03-15', ... '2021-10-02', '2021-10-03', '2021-10-04', '2021-10-05', '2021-10-06', '2021-10-07', '2021-10-08', '2021-10-09', '2021-10-10', '2021-10-11'], dtype='object', length=8256)

So, put the newtime in x. Someone know how to do this? Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

I think 'sun.font.FontManager'was removed with Java7, so if you must use it (I'd recommend against it and look for another package instead) you could try running it with java6.